# Export a SCN file out of iOS?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am writing a simple 3D program that creates some models I need to save. I can easily save and open the model:

```
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
   let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
   sceneView.scene.write(to: path, options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
}
```

But where can I get the model out of iOS? (For images I used to save to Photo Album and the user can get the files from there, but what about 3D models?)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quickest solution would be to save the file out to an iCloud storage directory, using the UIDocument classes. Apple has some generation documentation on it at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html.

Alternatives include writing to Dropbox or other cloud services (OneDrive, GoogleDrive, etc) using one of those SDK's for direct write access.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think this is the best way for simple apps (especially the current non-AR version simply load/save from Photo Albums)?

Comment: If your output is images, then the photo library can be a nice choice since it's so accessible and lots of other apps access it. If you're outputing other formats (like DAE, USD, etc) from your code, you probably want to consider options that are more open (regular file system stuff). The photo library SDK's are effectively constrained to image (and video) formats.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So if I wanted to share the scene with friends with the same app, what's the suggestion?